# Different approaches to Queue creation in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

Say I'm creating a Vulkan application that is both graphically heavy and computationally intensive. Say I decide to split my program and have separate queues for graphics commands and compute commands. It's easy to query the queue families for either the `VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT` or `VK_QUEUE_COMPUTE_BIT` flags, but there are still several factors to consider. Lets assume I have 2 GPUs that each have multiple queue families. Which option would give me the greatest performance (assuming each GPU is of the same quality and one isn't a doodoo intel integrated GPU):

1. Selecting a single queue family that supports both graphics and compute, and creating 2 separate queues from this queue family.
2. Selecting 2 different queue families (both of the same GPU), one of which supports graphics while the other supports compute, and creating a single queue from each of those queue families.
3. Selecting a single queue from a single queue family from each GPU, one being responsible for graphics while the other is responsible for compute.

Comment: This is something that's going to be *extremely* hardware-dependent, and thus cannot be known a priori. Indeed, it can even be workload-dependent; a rasterization-heavy workload (like a depth pre-pass, which has no fragment shader) could leave some compute units idle and available for compute shader execution.

Comment: Yes, also depends on the dependencies between the work. If the graphics depend on the compute, then 3 sounds like nonsense ferrying data to-and-fro between GPUs. If there are no dependencies, then your question could be reduced to what queues you would choose on a single GPU.